# What is the CDN on the write.manifest.json used for?

Tags: spfx

I'm trying to learn how to deploy an SPFx clientSide webpart to an office 365 developer tenant site assets location.

I have specified the `https://myTenant.sharepoint/siteAssets` URL on the `write.manifest.json CDN` string.

I have run the `gulp bundle --ship` and the `gulp package-solution` commands and finally have loaded the webpart solution `sppkg` into the app catalog site **but I do not see anything on the siteAssets** library.

Ehen I try to add the webpart to a page, I get an error. I could not post the error as I don't have enough points to post the error contents.

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct gulp command sequence? Or has this command sequence been eliminated?

Answer (score 3):

Really new to this too, but I followed the guide at https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/deploy-web-part-to-cdn yesterday but was using my own host as CDN, so this is how I think it works:

gulp package-solution does not package the js, css or other assets.

You need to upload those assets to a location of your choice.

That location you specify in cdnBasePath is used when you generate the webpart with gulp package-solution.

I did like this:

- gulp --ship
- uploaded the generated files from temp\deploy to a CDN (in your case upload to https://mytenant.sharepoint/siteAssets )
- change the cdnBasePath to the URL of CDN
- run: gulp bundle --ship & gulp package-solution --ship
- Upload the new webpart solution sppkg to Sharepoint App again

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Completely correct.  As an added bonus, you should try out the public CDN feature - https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-365-public-cdn-developer-preview-release   and set your   "cdnBasePath": "https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/WhatYouUsedToHaveHere" where you basically prepend "publiccdn.sharepointonline.com" to the path.  Works like a charm, but you have to wait 15 minutes after configuring it.  Also, unless you access the js from a SharePoint URL, you will get a referrer error.

Comment: I think you want to run `gulp bundle --ship` before deploying the files from temp/deploy because that is the step that actually generates those files.